# What's the correct way to toggle plot spaces?

Tags: core-plot, scatter-plot

Scenario: 

1) Five different periods {3M, 6M, 1Y, 2Y & 3Y} that require 5 different ranges; and hence, the different plot spaces.

2) Each plot space will contain 4 duplicate plots (each could be toggled visible/hidden).  The only difference is their respective periods.

3) User presses a 'period button' to display its respective plot space.

All the plot spaces will initially be created with their respective plots & ranges.

**Question:** 
1) What's the best way to select any one of these plot spaces for human interaction?

Scenario - User select a period/plot splace.

2) Can plots/plot space share a common data & delegate source?

 
   I notice no reference to a particular plot space/plot within the plot's delegate/data source.  So I assume it would be better to have parallel delegate/data sources.

Answer (score 0):

1. If only one range will be visible at a time, why duplicate everything? Just make four plots and assign them to one plot space. Change the plot ranges (and axis labeling if necessary) whenever the user selects a different range. The plots will redraw automatically to reflect the new range.
2. Multiple plots can share a single plot space. You can mix and match as needed; see the Mac CPTTestApp for an example. It uses one plot space for two scatterplots and another independent plot space for two bar plots.

You can definitely share a single datasource and/or delegate among multiple objects. All of the Core Plot example apps do this. All datasource and delegate methods pass a reference to the plot or plot space as one of the parameters. You can use the `identifier` property to differentiate the various plots and/or plot spaces.

Comment: I tried to use the single plot space having a different labeling policy/period.  But apparently, I can NOT change the plot's X-Range, once it is set.

The initial range is set for 6 (#months) ticks for one label policy.  The new range/period sets the range to 54 (#data points) for a different label policy.  The resultant range is still 6 ticks.

Comment: Can you show your code along with before and after values for the plot ranges, labeling policy, and anything you're changing?